# How many times can I call Socket.BeginAccept in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am coming from Java programming language. I am just beginning my adventure with C# and .Net.
I am creating a Server socket application using C# - based on Microsoft example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example).
This is the sample code (from the page above):

```
while (true)
{
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
    allDone.Reset();

    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
    listener.BeginAccept(
        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
        listener);

    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
    allDone.WaitOne();
}
```

... where `allDone` is a `ManualResetEvent` defined in the class scope.
I can't understand what actually `listener.BeginAccept` does. For instance if I don't call method `allDone.WaitOne()` to wait until connection is made, then what would have happend - how many times the call to `listener.BeginAccept` method would execute (be successful) inside the loop until it starts waiting (or maybe it would crash eventually). I am probably **missing** something here. Can someone explain this to me please?

Regards,

Janusz

Comment: This is the legacy Async Mechanism. BeginAccept starts an accept asynchronously and returns immediatly. So if you leave out the WaitOne() this will spin until an exception occurs. As is, I guess the MRE will be set in the AcceptCallback, which will be called when a Client is trying to connect. I'd suggest to use the Task Async Pattern in favor of this outdated mechanism.

Comment: Couldn't delete the last sentence any more. I thought there would be a Task Async API to socket, but there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The intent here is for the `AcceptCallback` method to set the `allDone` event when a connection is accepted. The loop can then go on to accept another incoming connection while the just accepted one continues with whatever it needs to do.

You could have done other useful work on the listening thread after the call to `BeginAccept`, if you had any that made sense.

Oddly the documentation does not explicitly state (that I could find) what happens if you just repeatedly call `BeginAccept` without waiting, but my recommendation would be to not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what would you suggest to use instead of Microsoft example?

Comment: The example is fine, I think, as a guideline, just keep the event logic.

Comment: Is there a better API to use for server Socket in C# or this is the only one?

Comment: I've inadvertently found the answer for the last paragraph - if you keep calling BeginAccept you end up with a slow memory leak and eventual crash with an unmanaged exception.